# Angular universal and ngx translate showing translation keys when rendering the page

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, ngx-translate

I am building bilingual webpage with Angular and I am using ngx-translate. However, when rendering Server Side, it first shows JSON keys and only later the language. I know the problem might be that translations are not yet loaded when the page initially renders. But I could not find answer to the question how I can ensure that translation files are being preloaded and available on the server-side? How can I preload the files before rendering the Angular Application?

I have researched a lot and I found solution with using transferstate but it did not solve my issue. You can see what I tried here: https://andremonteiro.pt/ngx-translate-angular-universal-ssr/ . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not going deeper into the issue, but the first thing that comes on mind is to have placeholder text in a certain language so that it's displayed before the translation is applied. Another approach might be not to display the full content until the data is returned from the server - maybe by putting the loader/spinner and having your template under ngIf bound to the var that'll be true if data is received.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried second approach but I am not totally sure if it is the right way to solve it. Thanks a lot

Comment: [Here's a working project](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/tree/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp). I had to create my own [`TranslateJsonLoader`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/translate-loaders/translate-json-loader.ts), and add an [`AppBrowserModule`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/main.ts#L47) - [code](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.browser.module.ts#L12)

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.server.module.ts#L13) the `AppServerModule`

Comment: Have you found a solution? The issue seems to be the custom `TranslateLoader` inside `app.server.module.ts`, `getTranslation` is never called

Answer (score 0):

I think Angular's [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) might be the solution, your app will load after  APP_INITIALIZER Promise is resolved or the Observable is completed, in APP_INITIALIZER function you can load your translator.json first then your app will load with translated fields.